# MySQL 5.7 date field trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-5.7

I have installed recently MySQL 5.7 . Something weird is happening with a date column.

If I execute a SELECT query using that field in a WHERE section, I have a resultset, but when I use the same WHERE condition to UPDATE a row I get an ***Invalid date format*** error message.

Here is the **SELECT** sentence:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  FDpoCargTran
WHERE FDpoCargTran.Banco = '001'
      AND (FDpoCargTran.Conciliacion = '' OR FDpoCargTran.Conciliacion IS NULL)
      AND FDpoCargTran.Fecha = '2016-09-27'
```

This sentence returns 2 rows resultset, that's ok.

Now, Here's the UPDATE sentence:

```
UPDATE
  FDpoCargTran
SET
  Edo = 'C'
WHERE FDpoCargTran.Banco = '001'
      AND (FDpoCargTran.Conciliacion = '' OR FDpoCargTran.Conciliacion IS NULL)
      AND FDpoCargTran.Fecha = '2016-09-27'
      AND Deposito = 1041
```

And I get this error message:

```
Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'Conciliacion'
```

The **Conciliacion** columns is defined as:

```
`Conciliacion` date DEFAULT NULL,
```

If I remove the **Conciliacion = ''** condition, everything works fine.

Why empty string is not valid to evaluate the column in an UPDATE sentence and not in a SELECT?

Please, an idea!!!

Comment: is there data where `Conciliacion = ''` in your table? i see the column defined as `date default null`, which means you can either have a valid date or null and *not an empty string*.

Comment: No, There are only, date values or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, for `date` datatype, you cannot store something like White
>   Spaces or ' ' strings. You need to make the column to accept NULL
>   values and insert an actual NULL into it. This is not a problem in MySQL 5.7, its how `date` is set in databases.

Update is a DML statement, when you actually want to write something into table, or check for a condition, MySQL is unable to understand what ' ' is for the date column type.

So, you cannot have ' ', instead you can have `NULL` set. Thats how MySQL can check the condition and make appropriate changes!!

I would suggest, change it to NULL.

1. Alter your datetime column to varchar.
2. Import whatever table/database.
3. Update FDpoCargTran set Conciliacion=NULL where Conciliacion='';
4. Alter column back to datetime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will follow the steps you wrote. In that table there are only date values or null, there are not empty strings.  

;-)

Comment: Thanks & Welcome :)